# Is there any goddess named Pataal Bhairavi?

Tags: goddess

I watched the movie the other day named "pataal bhairavi " but in the movie, she looked like Maa Kali. Is there any goddess named Pataal Bhairavi?

Comment: yes there is a devi with name Pataal Bhairavi

Comment: Jeetendra movie right ? :)

Comment: ya it a kinda unique name of the movie

Comment: Note that Patala Bhairavi is not one of the 10 Mahavidyas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a goddess named Paatala Bhairavi. She is a fierce looking form of goddess [Bhairavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhairavi), who is one of the Maha Vidyas.

There is a temple dedicated to Paatal Bhairavi in the town of Rajnandgaon in the Indian state of Chhattisgarh. The temple is **[Barfani Dham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barfani_dham)**. The temple is constructed in three levels. The bottom level is for Patal Bhairavi, next is for Navadurga or Tripura Sundari and the upper is for Lord Shiva.

[image: Pataala Bhairavi]

<sup>Image taken from [this](https://youtu.be/Ur5si1n5LAA) Youtube video about the temple.</sup>